# How to install Typo3 in Windows 10 with XAMPP?

Tags: windows, xampp, windows-10, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have installed XAMPP in Windows, It is working perfectly. but when I installed Typo3 version 8 and it Showed some errors

- PHP OpenSSL extension not working.
- PHP extension soap not loaded.
- Current directory is not within in the current path.
- Low PHP Script Execution Time.
- PHP max_input_vars very low.
- Windows apache thread stack size.

> **But I can't able to fix the following:**

- PHP OpenSSL extension not working.
- PHP extension soap not loaded.
- Current directory is not within in the current path.
- Windows apache thread stack size.

What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full configuration for the Apache On windows server. This working fine with my windows 10 with SSL.

Find my gist here: https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f

Hope this will work for you.

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you, but how and where should I add this?

Comment: That's great, I have tried this, now it is working. but while proceeding the typo3 installation. The database selection list is empty and if I tried to create a new database I can't create a new one.

Comment: "Doesn't have sufficient privileges to create the database." That was my error. My PHPMyAdmin doesn't require any password to login so I left the credentials as blank in Step 2 i.e database connection of typo3. A username and password necessary to this?

Comment: you have to add user: root password blank and host: localhost

Comment: Thank you I have reached at the 98% complete. but I can't able to login to the typo3 backend, Database has been created but the tables have not created in the database

Comment: This might be an issue with your database privileges

Comment: That's it I have set privileges now. I can log in now. Finally Solved it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The errors above are not something you have to worry about. 
You don't need openSSL for development, it is working without soap (maybe this is used by TER), you have to paste all typo3 src in root path because windows doesn't support symlinks.

But if you want to make all things work you have to use `vagrant` or `docker`.

`Vagrant` requires VirtualBox or other Virtual machine tool.

But docker has a boilerplate ready to use: https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate

Comment: Thank you, Anyway, my first issue was solved. Now the problem is while proceeding installation I can't create a new database or rather not available to select existing.

Comment: maybe the user has not rights to create a database. so, just login in mysql ( with phpmyadmin or cli ) and create another database. You can select only an empty database.

Comment: I have created a database in PHPMyAdmin, but i can't available in the select box of database connection in typo3. My PHPMyAdmin doesn't have any password to log in. so i left the credentials as blank in database connection. What may the problem? any idea?

Comment: do you use the same db user also for typo3 installation ?

Comment: No, i'm using the default username as "admin" and password as "password"

Comment: That seems not to be TYPO3 problem itself, but something with your XAMPP installation. Try to connect to database with simple standalone script using ie. mysqli_connect.
If it works for PhpMyadmin, check it's config (xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php)
If it still doesn't work, try to add a user in mysql and set him priviliges to that database and authorise using this user.
(PhpMyadmin -> (your database) -> Priviliges -> Add user account -> (set Host name to Local / localhost) and "Grant all privileges on database [your database]