# Not able to login in typo3 backend

Tags: php, apache, typo3, window, typo3-9.x

I installed typo3 cms on my local window machine using composer and fixed all the suggestions given by typo3 installation page.

But when i tried to login in backend then i am not able to login as it says **Requested url not found on this server** and here is the url : typo3/login?loginProvider=1433416747
[image]
Any idea what am i missing here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some hint below might be help you,

- Check server configuration
- Probably check your htaccess configuration
- Check out answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044158/5961782

The gist I created for windows xampp server working for me. Attaching here too

Gist: https://gist.github.com/GhanshyamBhava/41d3a34acc11cec2a4828b0d4b2c840f

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your .htaccess configuration is wrong or missing.

Please make sure that the content of this file:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess
is present in the .htaccess file in your document root directory. Since Windows tends to add additional file extensions to files, make sure that the file is really named `.htaccess`.

And please make sure that your Apache has the module mod_rewrite activated.

Side note: if you want to have a painless local development environment, checkout [DDEV](https://ddev.com/). It comes with TYPO3 support right out of the box.